# how to migrate DB from MySql to MS-SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, data-migration

i want to migrate my whole DB from MySQL to MS-Sql server.
though i am open to use any tool,am restricted to use only free avilable tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistan (SSMA) for MySQL

- [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2005 for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6f14640-da22-4604-aaaa-a45de4a0cd4a&displaylang=en)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0E6168B0-2D0C-4076-96C2-60BD25294A8E&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thanx but,is this a version specific tool as am using version2008 and it was expecting version 2005

Answer (score 0):

export db from MySql (mysqldump), edit by hand to convert between variations of SQL language in the two platforms, then import into MS-SQL.

Comment: I guess you didn't detect my sarcasm :)